# How to center Navbar and logo using sitespecific CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I have been struggling to figure out this problem. It seems like it would be a quick fix using CSS but i can't seem to find the proper CSS rules to make the changes. I am wanting to center the navigation bar as well as the header image for this website http://breespecific.co.nf

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you have two primary options:

1. Define the `width` or `max-width` of the item to be centered, and add `margin: auto;`
2. Give the item to be centered `display:inline-block;` and it's parent container `text-align:center;`

In both cases, the item you are trying to center **should not have any floats** on them, and they will display centered relative to the width of the parent.

In your specific page, `.navbar-header {text-align:center;float:none;}` and `#logo {display:inline-block;}` should take care of the logo, and `#main-menu '{display: inline-block; float: none;}` and `.navbar-ex1-collapse {text-align:center;}` should accomplish what you are wanting (don't forget to take the floats out of your media queries for these, as well).

If you want to use the other method in a responsive page, you would most likely want to set a `max-width` that is a percentage, and then `margin:auto;`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the floats from `.navbar-header` and `.main-nav` add `text-align:center` the header will be centered but the nav needs another rule, remove the `float:left` from the `.main-menu li` and make it `display:inline-block` now the `text-align:center` will be in effect so the nav will be centered too.

As you have not provided a fiddle i have no way of posting the code example but it is implemented simple enough.

Comment: I was able to fix the logo. But I am still not understanding how to shift the navbar to the same centered position as the logo. When I looked for the .main-menu li tag I cannot seem to find it. I found .menu-main, is that what you mean?

Comment: Soory for the late response, the li tag is just the child of the `.main-menu` tag you found you need to add the styles there.